# How to build this layout in Android?

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, layout, screen

i'm new to Android and i managed to finish my app. I was supposed to convert an iOS app to an Android one, so the WS were developed. I'm near to finish the app but two issues are remaining. I can't manage to make the same layout for the both two last. The two first images are iOS, and the last are Android. I don't understand the rules of RelativeLayout like AutoLayout for iOS, how do i make the home look great on every screen (that is to say, the good size for each button and well organized). At the moment, i managed to make the first 3 imageButtons ok, but on bigger screens the size of those buttons don't fit the screen entirely, how come ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

[imageHomeiOS http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/781886CapturedcranduSimulateuriOS3juil2014210948.png](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/781886CapturedcranduSimulateuriOS3juil2014210948.png)
[imageProfileiOS http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/583953CapturedcranduSimulateuriOS3juil2014211025.png](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/583953CapturedcranduSimulateuriOS3juil2014211025.png)
[imageHomeAnd http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/695608Capturedcran20140722190415.png](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/695608Capturedcran20140722190415.png)
[imageProfileAnd http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/313733Capturedcran20140722190428.png](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/313733Capturedcran20140722190428.png)

Comment: From your question, I guess you are trying to view a screen developed on a particular resolution with the devices having different resolution? If so your view layout files has to set for all required resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the perfomance as I get lint: **nested weight is bad for perfomance.** 
But try, I think for 7 buttons it will not affect to the perfomance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wow this is just so perfect ! Thank you very much ! For other people that happen to have this problem, add android:scaleType="centerInside" in each imageButton in order to have proper scaling of your image ! PERFECT ! Thanks a lot, i will find by myself for the other layout !

Answer (score 0):

Try using weighted layouts instead of a RelativeLayout.  You can define a horizontal linear layout to have a weightSum = 3, then give each button a layout_weight = 1.  The weight sum will essentially divide the screen up into that many parts, regardless of the screen size, and give a portion of each division to the elements that you give the weight to.  Make sure that when you define the layout_width of the individual elements, you define it as 0dp.  The width of the elements will no longer be set by the layout_width tag, it will be set by the weight that it takes up.